# Number of classes in project/workspace

Tags: objective-c, xcode, code-metrics

Is there any way to get **the number of classes** in a project or the complete workspace in Xcode?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use [cloc](http://cloc.sourceforge.net) which can also be installed via [Homebrew](http://brew.sh): `brew install cloc`.

Cloc is an open source command line tool for counting lines of code, but it also provides the count of files grouped by file type. The simplest form is `cloc <path-to-your-project-dir>` but the output can be configured by parameters.

A more complex solution (IMHO too complex) is, using [Sonarqube](http://www.sonarqube.org) with an Objective C plugin. Sonarqube has a nice interface and many functions, but just for counting classes, it's way to much.

Answer (score 8):

A simple way to get a rough idea for a project is by checking the **Compile Sources** section of the project's **Build Phases**. The compile sources will list all source files (.m, .swift) and doesn't include any headers.

Assuming roughly one class per source file, this will give you a ballpark idea of how many classes there are in your project at a glance. Note that this doesn't include any embedded projects or frameworks.

[image]